# PHP Jquery UI on update order change datetime of following rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm using following script to order my mysql table rows via php simple page. Here's my Javascript section:

```
$( "#mytable tbody" ).sortable({
update: function(event, ui) {
    $.post("order.php", { trows: $('#mytable tbody').sortable('serialize') } );
}
});
```

And here's my order.php

```
parse_str($_POST['trows'], $pageOrder);
foreach ($pageOrder['row'] as $key => $value) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE plan_produkcji SET `priorytet` = '$key' WHERE `id` = '$value'") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

What I'm looking for now is to get some basic idea on how to perform update another field in database on row change order event. The procedure is going to look like this - all rows except order have also start and end date. If user drags a date before existing earlier dates all the following dates should update (move in time) to be after the end date of this event which is going to be first. Example

Start date end date
14-07-2015 17-07-2015
17-07-2015 20-07-2015
etc.

If user adds a row with start date 21-07-2015 and end date 23-07-2015 and moves the row before the first row (14-07) the start date should update to 23-07-2015 and end date to 25-07-2015 and so on.

I'm new to javascript and jquery so I would be grateful for examples. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post `$pageOrder`? I have the feeling your `foreach` loop is incorrect for the structure of your array.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Waflix I get my $pageOrder from <tr id='row_".$row['id']."'> on each row of the table.

Comment: @Waflix update on your question my array should look like this: `[row] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
    )` where left side is the priorytet (order) and right is id of the record in table.

Comment: If the above is too complicated I would also be satisfied with the idea on how to move the start date/end date range for all rows in table that follow the updated/newly inserted row -> what I came up with right now is to select the current start date and the new start date and also current end date and new end date for edited row -> then I calculate the difference in minutes and lastly I execute the query to update the start_date and end_date with sum of the start/end dates differences in minutes by mysql + INTERVAL ".$count." MINUTE", but this is not working as expected right now.